# "Unknown root exit status." error in a Next.JS web app

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema, next.js13

I am facing the following problem in a *NextJS* app ?

The code below leads to an error. More precisely this line:

```
const theResult = await audioChunks(chanlID) // This leads to an error !!
```

is causing trouble. Indeed if I comment it out the error goes away.

Here is the code I am referring to:

```
import audioChunks from "@/lib/flow";
import VoiceUnit from "./VoiceUnit";


export default async function AudioList({chanlID}: {chanlID: string}) {
    const theResult = await audioChunks(chanlID) // This leads to an error !!

    return <div>
        {
            <div>KIKO+-+HIHO</div>
            // theResult.map(item => (
            //  <div key={item.voiceRecordID as string}>
            //      JIjiKIko
            //      {/* {item.channelID}::{item.voiceRecordID}:::{item.timeStamp} */}
            //  {/* <VoiceUnit channelID={item.channelID}
            //                       voiceRecordID={item.voiceRecordID} /> */}
            //  </div>
            // ))
        }
    </div>
} /* End of AudioList */
```

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #329; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=329 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

I checked the provided link and the full text of the error is this:

```
Unknown root exit status.
```

Now, since *audioChunks* seems to be the culprit. Here is the source code for the *audioChunks* function:

```
import mongoose, {Schema,Model,models} from "mongoose"
import connectMDB from "./mongoDB"


export default async function audioChunks(channel:string) {
    const speakSchema = new Schema({
        channelID: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        voiceRecordID: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        timeStamp: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    })

    interface SpeakDoc extends Document {
        channelID: string
        voiceRecordID: string
        timeStamp: number
    }

    interface SpeakModel extends Model<SpeakDoc> {}

    const theModel = models.Voice ? (models.Voice as SpeakModel) :
                                            mongoose.model<SpeakDoc, SpeakModel>
                                                    ('Voice',speakSchema,'vxads')

    await connectMDB()
    const theResult = await theModel
    // .find({})
    .find({channelID:{$eq:channel}})

    return theResult
} /* End of audioChunks */
```

Is there any mistake or anything suspicious in the code ?

Please let me know if some other piece of information is needed.

Addition:

And this is the contents of the mongoDB.tsx file:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const uri = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MDB_URI_AUDIO!,
            connectMDB = async () => mongoose.connect(uri)

export default connectMDB
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `./mongoDB` as well?

Comment: @Robin Thomas. Yes I just did it. Adding it to the post, please take a look.

Comment: On a side not, don't expose the mongodb credentials (`NEXT_PUBLIC_MDB_URI_AUDIO`) in your frontend. Move it to your backend (or server component)

Comment: Can you verify the `mongoose.connect` works fine with your url?

Comment: @Robin Thomas.

Thank you for the note.

As far as I am aware, I am only using NEXT_PUBLIC_MDB_URI_AUDIO in server components and have it stored on my backend.

But did you notice something suspicious or a bad practice ?

Comment: @Robin Thomas. Concerning mongoose.connect working fine with my url. I may not fully understand the concern.

But I can say that it allows me to get data. Indeed having this annoying error doesn't mean I can get access to no data.

Beside, assuming NEXT_PUBLIC_MDB_URI_AUDIO is:

"mongodb+srv://username:password@myapp.xyxz.mongodb.net/DBNAME"

I can connect with mongo-shell like this:
mongosh "mongodb+srv://myapp.xyxz.mongodb.net/" --apiVersion 1 --username username --password password

and then do:

> use DBNAME

Does that fully answer your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255304/discussion-between-robin-thomas-and-michel).

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error occurring in my NextJS app just now, and I narrowed it down to a client component that I had named `app.tsx`, that I was importing as:

```
import App from './components/app';
```

...and then using/calling as:

```
<App user={...} />
```

Not saying that's the source of your problem, but beware that NextJS seems to hold "App" as a reserved word, of sorts. Or, maybe the more likely case, is that a config file somewhere was getting confused with app the router path vs app the client component. When I renamed `app.tsx` to `appComponent.tsx` everything was fine, and no more `"Unknown root exit status"`.

Are you able to back your changes out to the extent that this problem goes away? If so, maybe you could narrow down things as you go from there, and hopefully find the problem.

I hope that helps. All the best!